# Civi posting additional records for recurring PayPal transactions

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, debugging

I'm having problems with recurring transactions with Paypal Pro.  It's posting additional financial_trxn and financial_item records.

I have exported an example including the following tables:

- [civicrm_contribution](https://www.dignityusa.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/csv/civicrm_contribution.csv)
- [civicrm_contribution_recur](https://www.dignityusa.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/csv/civicrm_contribution_recur.csv)
- [civicrm_entity_financial_trxn](https://www.dignityusa.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/csv/civicrm_entity_financial_trxn.csv)
- [civicrm_financial_item](https://www.dignityusa.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/csv/civicrm_financial_item.csv)
- [civicrm_financial_trxn](https://www.dignityusa.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/csv/civicrm_financial_trxn.csv)
- [civicrm_line_item](https://www.dignityusa.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/csv/civicrm_line_item.csv)

Looking at the entity_financial_trxn table, instead of one entry for the contribution and one for the fee, two are generated for each. (Contributions: 283111, 283114; fees: 283112, 283116) Also, the second contribution record (283114) does not have an associated financial_item record created.

In the financial_trxn table, the contribution transaction is entered twice (ids: 141185, 141187).  The first entry does not have a valid payment processor code.  The second does not have the net value calculated or a valid status code.  ALso, the fees are also entered twice (ids: 141186, 141188).  The first entry is missing the payment processor code.

Since there are two entries for fees in the financial_trxn table, there are also two entries in the financial_item table (ids: 142094, 142096).

So the contribution information is not fully correct in either financial_trxn record.  The second fee record in the financial_trxn table is correct.  All of these additional records are making the bookkeeping reports inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to replicate on the demo site in this case, which suggests posting an issue in JIRA is okay without that step -thanks for asking.

However, as this is widely-used functionality it's possible you have something misconfigured or misinterpreted rather than there being an error in the code suitable for a JIRA issue bug report.

Could you edit your question here to include the relevant original and subsequent records from civicrm_contribution, civicrm_entity_financial_trxn, civicrm_financial_trxn and civicrm_financial_item as well as the civicrm_contribution_recur record? Please refer to the spec for the entries expected in each table for each contribution at 
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviAccounts+Data+Flow and explain how there are too many entries.

(Sorry there's no spec for the contribution_recur table but it wasn't affected by CiviAccounts work.)